# CakePHP Element with a public property

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-2.0, cakephp-2.1, cakephp-2.3

I am still really new to CakePhp and had a question about elements.  I want to create a re-usable control for my web application.  Essentially a control that I can just build once and drop on any page.  This seems to be what an element is for, correct?  I have successfully created this control (which is just essentially a drop down list that allows the user to type and retrieves values asynchronously from the database) but wanted a way to expose a public property in the control to any view that is using it.  So, the control would have a public variable that gets changed but the controls logic.  Then, I want that variable to be accessible to the php code in the view that is using it.  Can this be done?  If so, how?  I've tried just creating a public variable in the head of my control but it comes up undefined in the view.

Thanks,
jason

Comment: did you see [this](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/views.html#passing-variables-into-an-element)? Is this what you are trying to achieve?

Comment: Thanks for your response.  This seems to be a way to pass data into an element.  I'm trying to pass data out of it.

Answer (score 0):

You will have to create a "public action" that can be called from every view regardless of the controller you're working on. In other words, create an action in AppController, let's call it "foo", then your element will simply call to the action "foo"

Comment: Thanks for your response.  So, there's no way to do this within the element itself?  It doesn't seem like I should have to create a function in the AppController and have to post back every time I want the value thats found in the client side.

Comment: What exactly do you want to do inside the element? 
If you want to do business logic then you would be breaking the MVC architecture

Comment: well, the element has has a mix of forms to create a dropdownlist that the user can type into, which will then hit a database and auto populate the drop down list.  What I would like to have happen is that when the user selects an item in the drop down list, it would set a property (and ideally raise an event) that would be accessible to the view.  In .Net, I would be able to access this property like Dim test = myControl.SomeProperty.

Comment: Well, I see that you will need to hit the database, thus some logic is needed right? So stick to MVC achitecture. I also guess that there is at least one model you want to work on(you mentioned you are hitting the database), thus I would create (maybe you have already done that) a controller for that model, then in your element call that controller/action [making use of requestAction](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/controllers.html#Controller::requestAction).

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use the element to any view, here is what you do.

Whenever you called, that element, you can change the variable value and you can use that variable in that element but with the same logic in the element.

```
echo $this->element('your_element', array('variable' => 'value'));
```

Is this what you want?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `element` or maybe need a `requestAction`.

If you want to use it as a generic element in a View

```
echo $this->element('my_element', array('variable' => 'value'));
```

Or if you want to do only the function for any View

```
$my_var = $this->requestAction('/Controller/action/maybe_a_param');
```